# Try-with-resources - Does it automatically close the connection? Java

Tags: java, connection, prepared-statement, hikaricp

I've been working on a SQL utility and I am trying to set the parameters inside a prepared statement in multiple functions.

To lessen the code, I have a function that returns a prepared statement where all the params are set.

***My question is:***
Does the connection reference in the `configureStatement()`  get closed using the try with resources in the `query()`? If not how can the code be refactored to close the `PreparedStatement` and the `Connection` every time?

```
    public void query(String queryString, List<String> queryParams, Consumer<ResultSet> sqlConsumer)
    {
        try (PreparedStatement preparedStatement = this.configureStatement(queryString, queryParams))
        {
            sqlConsumer.accept(preparedStatement.executeQuery());
        } catch(SQLException exception)
        {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    private PreparedStatement configureStatement(String query, List<String> queryParams) throws SQLException
    {
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = this.getConnection().prepareStatement(query);
        for (int i = 0; i < queryParams.size(); ++i)
            preparedStatement.setString(i, queryParams.get(i));

        return preparedStatement;
    }
```

Comment: Is the question if the connection gets closed with `try-with-resources` on the `PreparedStatement` or do you want to ask a different question about restructuring your code which closes the connection after running a query? Please [edit] your post to make it clear what single question you want to ask.

Comment: @Progman Yes, that's my basic question.  I have edited it to make it a little more clear.

Comment: Which database system and which JDBC client/version/library are you using?

Comment: Mysql with HikariCP so com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a question about try-with-resources, but about the `close` method of `PreparedStatement`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the try with resources does not close the `Connection` that is used inside the `PreparedStatement`.
Only the `PreparedStatement` and its `ResultSet` are closed.

[When a Statement object is closed, its current ResultSet object, if one exists, is also closed.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#close--)

It is possible to reuse a `connection` to execute many `PreparedStatements`. Each of which is closed after usage. When the `connection` is no longer needed it can be closed as well.

You could perhaps check it like this:

```
public void query(String queryString, List<String> queryParams, Consumer<ResultSet> sqlConsumer)
{
    Connection connection;
    try (PreparedStatement preparedStatement = this.configureStatement(queryString, queryParams))
    {
        connection=preparedStatement.getConnection();
        sqlConsumer.accept(preparedStatement.executeQuery());
    } catch(SQLException exception)
    {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
    if(connection!=null){
        System.out.println("Is Connection closed:"+connection.isClosed());
    }
}

private PreparedStatement configureStatement(String query, List<String> queryParams) throws SQLException
{
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = this.getConnection().prepareStatement(query);
    for (int i = 0; i < queryParams.size(); ++i)
        preparedStatement.setString(i, queryParams.get(i));

    return preparedStatement;
}
```

A refactoring that closes connections by using the try-with-resources with multiple statements:

```
public void query(String queryString, List<String> queryParams, Consumer<ResultSet> sqlConsumer)
    {

        try ( Connection connection=this.getConnection(); 
              PreparedStatement preparedStatement = this.configureStatement(connection, queryString, queryParams);)
        {
            sqlConsumer.accept(preparedStatement.executeQuery());
        } catch(SQLException exception)
        {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(connection!=null){
           connection.close();
        }
    }

private PreparedStatement configureStatement( Connection connection,String query, List<String> queryParams) throws SQLException
    {
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        for (int i = 0; i < queryParams.size(); ++i)
            preparedStatement.setString(i, queryParams.get(i));

        return preparedStatement;
    }
```

Comment: That's what I figured.  Any ideas on how I could refactor to make this happen? I want to have a query() and execute() function where both takes that param list.  I don't want to copy-paste the for loop code in both functions.  I'd rather have a method that does it automatically.  But the connection needs to be closed after it completes.  I guess I could close the connection manually in each function but that looks a little messy.

Comment: Sure I will update the example, but perhaps you can also update the question to reflect that need. So it is easier for future readers to understand the question/answer.

Comment: This is what I was looking for.  Another way I just thought of was closing the connection manually in the consumer itself.  Think I'll use this instead though.  Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome, closing the connection manually is also possible. But you can leverage the try-with-resources to ensure both the connection and the prepared statement are closed.

Answer (score -1):

Q: What makes you think returning an object from one of your own methods won't allow the object to be "closed" in a Java try with resources?

From the Java documentation:

> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html
>
> > Any object that implements java.lang.AutoCloseable, which includes
> > all objects which implement java.io.Closeable, can be used as a
> > resource.

The key issue: the object returned from your method must implement `java.lang.AutoCloseable`.  In your case, it does:

> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html
>
> **Interface PreparedStatement**
>
> - All Superinterfaces:
>
>   AutoCloseable, Statement, Wrapper

Comment: I know that the PreparedStatement returned from that function will be closed.  However, the connection that is referenced inside the configureStatement function needs to be closed as well.  To my knowledge, closing the statement with a try-resource did not close the connection too.  I guess they do though.

Comment: Your code clearly shows both the connection and your method that creates the prepared statement  are in the same try/resource block.  Hence both are closed when the block exits.  It sounded like your question was just asking about the "configureStatement()" method - hence my reply.  No, of *course* closing a prepared statement doesn't necessarily close the connection.  Why would you even think that???